# Mosaic many rasters in ArcGIS is slow

Tags: arcpy, performance, mosaic

I am trying to merge 166 tiles into a single world raster (500 meters resolution) through ArcGis "Mosaic to new raster" tool with a simple Python script. The process seems incredibly slow. Before starting to study alternative approaches (from similar questions GDAL_merge seems the most correct) is there any ArcGis setting that can speed up the process?

Comment: I've found it's very slow as well. I know of no definitive solution, though for me it worked sort of ok to divide the process over separate mosaics (e.g. 10 times 16 rasters) and mosaic their output together.

Comment: Are you using the blend mode?

Comment: No. the tiles are not overlapping. This is the actual string used on the script arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(stringListFiles[:-1], outputFolder, tifFile, "", "8_BIT_UNSIGNED", "", "1", "FIRST", "LAST")

Comment: How large are your 166 tiles, i.e. how many rows and columns?

Comment: Columns and rows (5783, 7704)

Comment: Do you have access to digital image processing software such as Erdas Imagine?

Comment: It may help to explicitly set a cell size.  Otherwise it will need to compute a cell size from the input which may require more processing.